# Identifying where memory allocation is happening in core

Tags: performance, haskell, memory-management, ghc

This might be a silly question or too open-ended, but what do I look for in GHC core output to understand where memory allocations are happening? My motivation is to better understand how to optimize code like [this](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2014/01/optimising-haskell-for-tight-inner-loop.html), or e.g. to try to avoid preemption during critical sections in concurrent code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let`s is typically where this happens, assuming the variable being bounds id not of kind `#` (i.e. a let-bound `Int#` doesn't cause allocation.) However, it's really STG which defines exactly where it happens.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/GeneratedCode) looks like it will be helpful if I want to try to understand some of STG. So is the idea that if we're `let` binding an `Int#` or other unboxed thing that it's already in the stack or something?